# can functions be executed directly in dictionary in python rather than putting only a call to function in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

when trying to implement a switch-case statement in dictionary i tried following code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
N = int(input())
lst=[]
dict={
    'insert' : lst.insert,
    'print' : print(lst),
    'remove' : lst.remove,
    'append' : lst.append,
    'sort' : lst.sort,
    'pop' : lst.pop,
    'reverse' : lst.reverse
}   
for _ in range(N) :
     key,*args=input().split()
     args=list(map(int,args))
     if key in dict :
        dict[key](*args)
     else :
        continue
```

the output i got

```
5              //value i gave to N
[]
insert 0 5
append 5
print
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p1.py", line 17, in <module>
    dict[key](*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

so then i thought that we can only call functions in the dictionary so i tried

```
def insert(i,e):
    lst.insert(i,e)

def prin() :
    print(lst)

def rem(e):
    lst.remove(e)

def append(e):
    lst.append(e)

def sort():
    lst.sort()

def pop():
    lst.pop()

def reverse():
    lst.reverse()

N=int(input())
lst=[]
switch={
'insert' : insert,
'print' : prin,
'remove' : rem,
'append' : append,
'sort' : sort,
'pop' : pop,
'reverse' : reverse
}
for _ in range(N) :
    key,*args=input().split()
    args=list(map(int,args))

    if key in switch :
        switch[key](*args)
    else :
        continue
```

and it worked correctly

> My doubt is in the wrong code why was the print statement in the dictionary exectuting directly and printing the empty list []

Comment: Using a dictionary *is not implementing a swtich statment*. In any case, when you use `print(lst)` **you are calling the print function there**

Comment: In the first code you print the empty list and put the return value, None, in the dictionary. You actually only needed to change that one, not all of them: `'print': lambda: print(lst)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can appreciate in the first code snippet that there is syntax difference that is producing your error, let's take a look here:

```
'insert': lst.insert,
'print' : print(lst),
```

Now in the second code when you redefined it you used:

```
def insert(i,e):
    lst.insert(i,e)

def prin() :
    print(lst)
```

Can you see the difference in the parenthesis and how you were passing the arguments?
Remember when you use functions as parameter that they are first class objects which can be referenced and called. In your first attempt you were calling the function print(lst) first and using as a parameter its result, an empty list. You don't need to modify all the code, just don't call print and pass the parameter lst the same way you did with the other functions.